# curl: (35) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, mmc

I am trying to setup a https server for local development.I am using a Windows 10 machine . I have generated a self signed Certificate using openssl. I used the following commands.

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
rm csr.pem
```

This is demo Server code (NodeJS) which outputs "hello world".

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};


https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

I have accessed the URL from command prompt using curl command

```
curl https://localhost:8000
```

I am getting the error as

```
curl: (35) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
```

I have added the self signed certificated in the "Trusted root certificate authority" store using the "Microsoft management Console (mmc)". This is my
[Certificate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVokq.png).

I don't understand where i am going wrong. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: (1) this is not a programming or development question or problem -- although I don't find a dupe on SU or SF as I would expect (2) the CommonName = CN in the cert (or the SubjectAlternativeName = SAN if used, which your simple OpenSSL doesn't) must match the name(s) used in the URL to access the server, i.e. if you use `https://localhost:port` the CN must be `localhost` (note without port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Common Name (CN) in your certificate is "myown digital certificate" while it should be "localhost". Recreate the CSR and explicitly set the CN like so

```
openssl req -new -key key.pem -subj "/CN=localhost" -out csr.pem
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the -k switch with CURL to ignore SSL cert errors. Obviously, this is not recommended for an environment where you want to make sure the cert is good.